# how to get Github Pull Request Comments Thread Using github API

Tags: github

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

I Need PR Comments like this

ex)
[image]

```
[
    {
        avartar : 'img_link',
        author : 'MoonSupport',
        description: 'dd\ntt',
    },
    {
        avartar : 'img_link',
        author : 'MoonSupport',
        description: 'review1',
    },
    {
        avartar : 'img_link',
        author : 'MoonSupport',
        description: 'review2',
    }
]
```

Is there API that work it?

Please find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Rest API v3

Using API v3, you can get the PR comments using

```
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO_NAME/issues/NUMBER/comments
```

Example for [this PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21214) : https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21214/comments

You can get the PR review comments using :

```
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO_NAME/pulls/NUMBER/comments
```

Example for [this PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21214) : https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/pulls/21214/comments

But this doen't include the review body text (which is at the same level as a comment in the Github Web UI). The following get the body text of the reviews :

```
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO_NAME/pulls/NUMBER/reviews
```

Example for [this PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21214) : https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/pulls/21214/reviews

#### GraphQL API v4

Using [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/), to get both comments, reviews comments and review body text :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    pullRequest(number: 21214) {
      reviews(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          bodyText
          createdAt
          author {
            login
          }
          comments(first: 100) {
            nodes {
              author {
                login
              }
              body
            }
          }
        }
      }
      comments(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          author {
            login
          }
          createdAt
          body
        }
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Rest API don't work...
It just provide code review comments( not all thread ).

But Grahpql work So I will try this way.
Thank you!!